# How do I extract code from markdown code block string?

Tags: javascript, string, markdown

If I have this string like this

````
```
console.log()
```
Hello
````

or

````
Hello
```
console.log()
```
````

or

````
```console.log()``` Hello
````

or

````
Hello ```console.log()```
````

How do I get just the console.log() string?

---------------------------------------------- Edit ----------------------------------------------

The regex I use is the combination between regex answered by @Himanshu Tanwar with the one suggested by @ASDFGerte

````
var code = s.match(/```([^`]*)```/)[1]
````

Comment: You can try `split()`ing on "```".

Comment: the easiset is to render to a fragment, then use the dom/css selectors to hit it.

Comment: @dandavis Would you like to explain more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing it with regular expression

````
var s = "```console.log()```Hello";

var code = s.match(/```(.*)```/)[1]
````

Comment: Remember to `.trim()` the result :)

Comment: preferrably use `([^\`]*)` or you will get unwanted results if the string includes several code blocks.

Comment: @ASDFGerte You mean that the regex is like this, `/\`\`\`([^\`]*)\`\`\`/`?

Comment: Yes. Try both with `"\`\`\`console.log()\`\`\`Hello\`\`\`console.log()\`\`\`Hello".match(` and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Look at follow regex, it's match all your strings:

````
/```[^`]*```/gmi
````

Working example can be found here https://regex101.com/r/hcRumt/1